# Date format changing in vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm using date picker :

```
 <Datepicker :format="format"  v-model="form.start" name="start"></Datepicker>
```

Its format is something like this :

```
data(){
        return {
            format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
            form: new Form({
                id:'',
                start: '',
```

Now on form submit i have appended it to form Data like this

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('start', this.form.start);
```

When i console i get date something like this `Sat Jul 03 2021 19:11:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

In the controller i am validating date like :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {   
        $this->validate($request, [
            'start' => 'required|date|after_or_equal:'.now()->format('d-m-Y'),
```

> Output:

```
The start is not a valid date
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide datepicker package you're using, npmjs link or exact name. There is a lot of Datepicker vue package out there.

Comment: @nmfzone: using this datepicker https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker, but issue when i append `this.form.start` to `formData.start`

Comment: Hey, is your issue still exists?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen here, it's by design.

Please take a look on [this code](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker/blob/v1.6.2/src/components/DateInput.vue#L27), your issue happens when you're select the date via @keyup, then you'll get Date object (please take a look [here](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker/blob/v1.6.2/src/components/DateInput.vue#L80)). But, if you're select the date via Calendar, the value should be string with that format, not Date object.

To overcome your issue, I suggest you to do this.

1. Specify the format props like this

```js
data() {
    return {
        format: (value) => value,
        ...
    };
}
```

2. Then, you may manually format the date by using dayjs, install it first `npm install dayjs --save`, then

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('start', dayjs(this.form.start).format(this.format));
```